# How do philosophers answer a question like 'How do you know something exists?'

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, ontology, proof, evidence

I recently watched a [video](https://youtu.be/i48zNH_olps) from Rationality Rules titled "The Argument from Personal Experience - Debunked (Why Personal Experiences are NOT Proof)". As the title reveals, the video's goal is to debunk the argument from personal experience that many theists commonly bring up to defend their belief in the supernatural. The argument is presented in a syllogistic form at [1:10](https://youtu.be/i48zNH_olps?t=70):

> 1. My account of my personal experience is infallible
> 2. I have personally experienced **visions of reincarnation**
> 3. Therefore, **reincarnation** exists

The argument is logically sound but relies on premises 1 and 2 being true, and the rest of the video focuses on refuting those premises.

I find the reasoning presented in the video to some extent compelling, but I noticed that the same can be said of left hands. Concretely:

> 1. My account of my personal experience is infallible
> 2. I have personally experienced **my left hand**
> 3. Therefore, **my left hand** exists

---

Ultimately, **how do you know your left hand exists? Or more generally, since everything is mediated by our own personal experience, how can we know anything for certain? These are clearly a philosophical question, so how do philosophers approach it?**

Comment: I'd engage you more in [the Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium), but apparently you've gotten yourself banned. If you can find a way to undo that, let me know. I'd be happy to engage in your drive to find your answers.

Comment: Your infallible personal experience includes the experience of other people, who may well contest its infallibility or refuse to accept as evidence experiences that they cannot reproduce.

Comment: I think the top section just proves that visions of reincarnation exist, not that reincarnation exist.

Comment: There is no argument here in the academic sense. The premises do not share anything in common which in  syllogism logic is called the middle term. So you vocabulary is already off on the term argument & then you use the term SOUND incorrectly. A sound argument must be valid and must have true premises. The first premise you state is subjective and not a fact. The point of syllogisms is NOT TO USE MODERN LANGUAGE OR EMOTIVE LANGUAGE. You must reduce all language into the mold of the syllogism not the other way around. The purpose is to catch deception. I clearly see there is a problem with this

Comment: @Logikal feel free to edit the question

Comment: Here is Peirce's response:"*reasoning should not form a chain which is no stronger than its weakest link, but a cable whose fibers may be ever so slender, provided they are sufficiently numerous and intimately connected*". Everything is fallible ([phantom limb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_limb) experiences are well-known, for example), but the fibers supporting the existence of left hands are far more numerous and cohesive with each other than those supporting reincarnations. Certainty does not come from one experience, or even all personal experiences together, taken by themselves.

Comment: As an experiment, you can always slap people with your left hand and record their perception of it. Repeat the experience enough times to establish a solid corpus of data, with as wide as possible a variety of subjects, both hand believers and hand deniers, to avoid bias. Establish a solid double blind protocol, where you don't know beforehand if the subject believes in your hand, and the blindfolded subjects ignore if you slap them with your hand or a glove full of rice. Also, notice how none of this experimental verification is possible with recollections of past reincarnations.

Comment: @armand: You would still need to trust your personal experience of seeing other people verifying the existence of your left hand. You would also need to trust your personal experience of your memory telling you that the experiment took place in the first place. More generally, you would still need to trust your personal experience of all what you see, hear, remember, etc.

Comment: Sure. But at that point you'd have fallen into sollipsism. Everything around you tells you your hand exists, each repeated observation corroborates it but you'd still choose to doubt. Then why bother eating, breathing? You were told it's important to stay alive, but can you trust this information? About the impracticality of such a view, see [On Certainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Certainty), the last book written by Wittgenstein.

Comment: He takes the same exemple you took, his hand, and argues that yes, metaphysicians can always say they doubt they have hands, yet they will still go on and live their lives as if they had hands. At the end of the day, the issue is practical more than metaphysical: you have to assume your experience is at least somewhat reliable to simply stay alive.

Comment: Edited to avoid the "off-topic" and "clarity objections".

Answer (score 2):

> How do you know your left hand exists? Or more generally, since everything is mediated by our own personal experience, how can we know anything for certain?

**Short Answer**

So, you've come to the right site because you can be advised that both questions are textbook examples of questions related to [metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/), and that depending on the answers to your metaphysical questions, the rest follows in your philosophy. The short answer to both your questions is 'It depends'.

**Long Answer**

You have asked two excellent questions which can be generalized: 'How can we know what exists?' and 'How can we know truth?'

The nature of existence is the domain of the [ontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology). Ontology is the study of what constitutes 'existence'. If you are serious about your philosophical studies, it would be best to pick up a book that gives an overview of some of the ontological discourse from contemporary sources. [*Ontology and Metaontology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ontology_and_Metaontology/Jy3bBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by Berto and Plebani is what I have in my library, but I'm sure there are many excellent works.

The nature of how we can be certain truths is the focus of [epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) which is concerned about truth. The dominant model historically is a criterion called [justified, true belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief#Justified_true_belief) (JTB), but was severely undermined by [Gettier problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem). Again, my library holds [Epistemology: Classic Problems and Contemporary Responses](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Epistemology/6hOxXxRAWcwC?hl=en&gbpv=0) by BonJour, but again, many good works are out there.

While you'll likely find an answer eventually to the questions which you ask that suit your [intuition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuition/) and logic, what is really important is that you understand that your metaphysical presumptions, that is, your ideas about epistemology, ontology, and and your [value-theoretic leanings](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/value-theory/) will largely determine your answers, and that philosophy to no small extent is depends on your studies in metaphysics, a lesson that was learned by the [logical empiricists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-empiricism/) and [logical positivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) when they underwent and failed to complete a program of eliminating metaphysics from philosophy itself.

Now, my personal response is easy for me to give. **How do I know what exists?** Well, for me existence is anything of which I am aware. Of those [phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenon), they are either physical or abstract, and anything that is physical can be affirmed by science; anything abstract is constrained only by the nature of an embodied intelligence.

---

Now, how do I know what is [true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True)? Well, I believe that all sources of belief need to be vetted by [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) and [empirical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism) means in a particular order culminating in goal-oriented skepticism which accepts that [scientific realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/) and a rejection of the supernatural is a good, but not perfect, framework from which I can organize my [Weltanschauung or worldview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldview). I believe that in a deeper context, [underdetermination of science theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/)   is exactly what allows science to function and suggests that [transcendental idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_idealism) serves as the best argument that the [territory is not the map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation).

So particularly, I know my hand exists because I see and feel it, others see and feel it, and it's physical basis is well established by atomic and evolutionary theory. I also know that nothing can be known with absolute certainty, and while I reject extreme forms of [skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_skepticism#Pyrrhonism), there is a bar that serves under ordinary language and experience: justified, true belief. Sure, there are cases that can be presented to refute it, but I am a probabilistic biological computer with [embodied intelligence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/), and I operate primarily with [defeasible reasoning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/) and heuristics. Where it fails, more epistemological methods can be established according to needs.

But I accept that everyone has different metaphysical inclinations and tools, and happily engage with them, because like the Roman Republic, I'm more interested in the payoff of new ideas and cooperation than I am in being a high priest of ideas and deciding who is 'right' and who is 'wrong', which is embracing binary logic in a very unsophisticated manner for psychological and political payoffs.

Keep asking good questions, and you'll get to an answer you're happy with. I say that in the same spirit as Antonio Damasio and his [naturalized epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology) and [his theory of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damasio%27s_theory_of_consciousness).

Good luck!